# I have a mess when doing "sudo apt update" Debian 10

Tags: debian, apt

I did the typical "sudo apt update" and at the end of the output i found this:

```
All packages are up to date.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/source/Sources' as repository 
'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster InRelease' does not seem to provide it 
(sources.list entry misspelt?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'edge/source/Sources' as repository 
'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster InRelease' does not seem to provide it 
(sources.list entry misspelt?)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and 
the previous index files will be used. GPG error: 
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/Debian_10 ./ InRelease: 
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
NO_PUBKEY DFA175A75104960E
W: Failed to fetch 
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/Debian_10/./InRelease  The 
following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 
DFA175A75104960E
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This might also be important so here are some lines of my /etc/apt/sources.list (i don't know if i should put the whole content of the file)

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ buster main
deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ buster main
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable edge
deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable edge
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
```

I still consider myself a noob, and I've searched for solutions but i haven't found them so i will appreciate your help a lot, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to post the whole content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following lines:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable edge
deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable edge
```

To

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable
```

to solve the following error:

```
All packages are up to date. W: Skipping acquire of configured file 
'stable/source/Sources' as repository 'https://download.docker.com
/linux/debian buster InRelease' does not seem to provide it
 (sources.list entry misspelt?)
```

You need to remove the docker source repository `deb-src`.

Then run:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Remove opensuse repository under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory.

Comment: Hi I followed your instructions and it helped a lot, thank you, but i still get something of the original warnings here it is: `All packages are up to date.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/source/Sources' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)`

Comment: @Marco see my edit , remove the `deb-src` for docker.